# Finding the slope of a curve at certain points dynamically

Tags: plot

I wonder if it possible to write a python code to find the slope of the attached plot (frequency vs. time). One point of the slope when the curve starts to decline after the dip. the another point is when the slope line touches the last point before the downward peak.

Also is it possible to make this code generic since I have hundred of this curves that I have to calculate the slope for each one?

Dynamic Plot :

[image: Dynamic Plot]